# How to say "Thanks" to the Ubuntu developers?

Tags: community

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a congrats ubuntu page?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/115257/is-there-a-congrats-ubuntu-page)

The release of Ubuntu 12.04 is imminent and it's (once again) quite a fine release.

Now I'd like to show my appreciation of all the work developers have put into Ubuntu over the last six months. What'
s the best way to do that?